# Risk of running TB and FF together?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I've seen such warnings, but haven't seen explanations of why it might possibly be risky to run the Tor Browser at the same time as running Firefox -  just general thoughts about how the 2 browsers might be sharing something. What, if any, are the particular reasons for concern?

Also, would any of the FF forks (Waterfox, Pale Moon, etc.) be better on that concern than FF itself?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was more of a risk before - when you manually configured the browser to use tor.

TBB is a standalone version of the browser, so it does not share anything with the 'regular' browser, but there is one risk that I can think of and that is that they both look the same ,and you can then easily enter something in the wrong browser, which then can be used to identify information, or that you mistakenly install a addon or something like that in the wrong browser.

Comment: Thanks, Stig, you are 100% right about confusing browsers - so put back the menu bar (hamburger, customize, then click 'menu bar') and I again see the TBB yellow icon which really stands out.

Comment: I misspoke above: I should have said "title bar", not "menu bar". Also, I have discovered that I can put back the title bar with the familiar yellowish world icon in Windows, but can't put back the title bar in Tails.

Answer (score 1):

Well,I can say if you do this,you are not at risk technically,because those two browsers  work independently and they do not share anything with each other.But there is another problem:when you are trying to type a website domain name and visit it anonymously in Tor browser,you may choose another normal firefox by mistakes and reveal your real public IP address.So you`d better not do this,okay?

Comment: Yes, GA, and in fact I have made that mistake in the past. I almost turned white a moment later when I realized what I had done. So I say that it's important to practice a lot, and get mistakes out of the way in practice. Everybody *will* make mistakes. :)